# Find CPU Usage at the moment C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed following code sample by using online example.But it didn't give me the percentage of CPU Usage.

```
    PerformanceCounter RcpuCounter;
    PerformanceCounter RramCounter;

    public void ResourcesCPU()
    {
        RcpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

        RcpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        RcpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        RcpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        string cpu = getCurrentCpuUsage();
    }

    public string getCurrentCpuUsage()
    {
        string Value1 = RcpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";

        return Value1;
    }
```

and then, I changed getCurrentCpuUsage() method as below.It gave me a value as CPU Usage.

```
public string getCurrentCpuUsage()
    {
        string Value1 = RcpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string Value2 = RcpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";

        return Value2;
    }
```

I know that it is possible to have different cpu usage in different time.But my Question is Why it didn't give me any value in the first algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the
>   first read operation returns 0.0. Resetting the performance counter
>   properties to specify a different counter is equivalent to creating a
>   new performance counter, and the first read operation using the new
>   properties returns 0.0. The recommended delay time between calls to
>   the NextValue method is one second, to allow the counter to perform
>   the next incremental read.